# Docker on Windows: lots of disk space in %TMP%/docker-index

Tags: docker-for-windows

I have one Windows guest image I built and I've been running containers from it for a few days. It's a decently large image, probably 20GB of data, and the containers grow fairly large as well. It works OK normally, until I run out of disk space...

Even when the container is shut down and removed, I still have 95GB of data in `c:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\docker-index\sha256`. That folder contains a few 30-40GB tar files. What are they, and do I need them? 95GB is a lot!

I'm using the standard Docker Desktop, Win11 Pro.

Answer (score 3):

According to here https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-index-exe-consuming-resources-for-7-hours/132769 it's an experimental feature that scans your images for known cve and generates sboms. You can disable it docker desktop -> Feature in development -> Experimental features -> untick the boxes

Answer (score 1):

I think the quesstion was how to get rid of the temp files.

I manually deleted everrything under docker-scout/sha256 and recovered almost 10GB.

No impact on existing containers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).